# Neo4j Social relationship Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am new to Neo4j.  Below is my social graph image which I have created in my Neo4j. Currently I am looking for a Cypher query which will fetch all Friends of "Rohit" who Like "Trekking"

[image: Social Graph]

I have tried the following but it is not working.

```
MATCH (:Profile{name:"Rohit"})-[:Friend]-(p:Profile) 
WITH p 
MATCH (p)-[l:Like]-(:Hobby{name:"Trekking"}) 
RETURN l
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? As an aside, I would think that `Trekking` would be a single node.

Comment: MATCH (:Profile{name:"Rohit"})-[:Friend]-(p:Profile) with p
MATCH (p)-[l:Like]-(:Hobby{name:"Trekking"}) return l

Comment: that seems like it would do what you would want; what did you expect? what are you experiencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the friend you should return `p` instead of `l`. Moreover, I think you don't need to use a `WITH` here (although you can, if you wish), you can try something like

```
MATCH (:Profile{name:"Rohit"})-[:Friend]->(p:Profile)-[:Like]->(:Hobby{name:"Trekking"}) 
RETURN p
```

This should work